# How to calculate `x^3 + ax + b mod p` with Golang big.Int

Tags: go, cryptography, ecdsa, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to find the **Y** coordinate for an elliptic point. I understand the formula is `y^2≡x^3+ax+b mod p`.

However I'm unsure of how I would actually program this in Go.

```
xCubed.Exp(X, 3, nil)
AX.Mul(A,X)

N.Add(XPow3, AX) // x^3 + ax
N.Mod(N, P) // mod p
N.Add(N, B) // (x^3 + ax) + b
N.Mod(N, P) // mod p

return N
```

Where xCubed,X,N,P,B are `*big.Int` and N represents y^2

I'm a noob to modular arithmetic, so my assumption mod P is applied to each operation; Is this the correct way to to calculate `x^3 + ax + b mod p`?

edit: should I have added AX.Mod(p) ?

Comment: you might want to take a look at this Java implementation: there is a method `getY`: https://github.com/google/tink/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/crypto/tink/subtle/EllipticCurves.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, by scouting some code in the [elliptic lib](https://golang.org/src/crypto/elliptic/elliptic.go?s=2055:2110#L55)

```
func GetY(x *big.Int, curve *elliptic.CurveParams) *big.Int {


    x3 := new(big.Int).Mul(x, x)
    x3.Mul(x3, x)

    threeX := new(big.Int).Lsh(x, 1)
    threeX.Add(threeX, x)

    x3.Sub(x3, threeX)
    x3.Add(x3, curve.B)
    x3.Mod(x3, curve.P)

    return x3.ModSqrt(x3, curve.P)
}
```

Comment: If you are just picking random x's and plugging them in you must be prepared for the possibility the square root does not exist, and `ModSqrt` returns nil.